# Does add more memory RAM decrease I/O wait?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, memory, io

My server is Ubuntu KVM and has 2 cores, 4GB RAM, and I use HDD, at moment I can't swap HDD to SSD.

I found this answear (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463819/351968) saying that adding more memory RAM can help, but I'm not sure because I did not found anything about it on the internet, the READ is heavy on my server.

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully read in memory caches are indeed possible but you will need to explore what's would be best for your application(s).

The premise here is to put the heavily read files into RAM that the app(s) may heavily hit instead of the massively slower HDD(s).